# How to retrieve path from URL in initiate method of custom authentication

Tags: apex, community, authentication, auth-provider

We have an external identity provider with custom apex provider and auth. provider configured. Beside this, we have configured different paths for each country using custom url. Now we want to get that path in initiate method of custom apex provider plugin and embed in authorization url.

We have tried ApexPages.currentPage() ( coming as null ) and URL.currentRequestURL() ( just returning base URL.

Is there any way to get path details in initiate method or any other workaround to pass language code to this method through custom url ?

Comment: Rethink your solution in terms of experience id. This might be overkill for localization but it's an option: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_identity_dynamic_extend_endpoint_expid.htm&type=5